# Http headers in subsequent calls / navigations in chrome custom tabs

Tags: java, android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am launching a chrome custom tab and setting customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers) its working as expected. However, I am in a situation.

When i launch the chrome custom tab with headers, and when redirection happens headers are not being carried forward to next request. How should i get it working?

Scenario is like 
Launch New chrome console tab (tab gets launched with headers as parsed in intent.putextra) > click any http link on loaded page OR if page gets auto redirected (any subsequent request happens without headers)

Example:
I launch "google.com" with customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers). I see parsed headers in request and google home page gets loaded. Now, suppose on the page i click "news" another request goes to google server . However, this time i dont see parsed headers in HTTP request.

In webview i could do it easily using

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    { 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
     view.loadUrl(url, getExtraHeaders()); return true;
     } 

});
```

Comment: ` use click / get auto redirected (happens without headers)` ???
 I didn't get that

Comment: @yates i have updated my question,  I mean any subsequent redirection or click on page url happens without the headers passed in first request using intent.putextra.

Comment: You say cct ; but the code is about webView.